# hide show div (but display first 200px)

Tags: jquery

I am using some code from a fiddle made by a member of StackOverflow. To hide show divs on click.

My issue is I wish to extend this , I will explain.

I have content loading from database, which lets say is approx 500px in height.
But On page load, I only want to show the first 200px height of this content, so user can click "Show More" and the remainder of the div slides down.

To keep things tidy, I would like to extend the use of the code , given on here if possible, so that my JS is tidy.

The code to hide/show content thus far is:

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#setup-ofi").click(function() {
    $("#closeable-ofi").slideToggle(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
            $("#setup-ofi").text("Hide Details \u25b2");
        }
        else {
            $("#setup-ofi").text("Show Details \u25bc");
        }
    });
});
```

});

The HTML

```
<h3>Property Details - <span class="sub-searchBlue"><a id="setup-ofi" href="javascript:;"> Show Details &#x25BC;</a></span></h3>
    <div id="closeable-ofi" style="display:none">
    content of db shows here
    </div>
```

FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/3x2uG/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find working sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/ezmilhouse/Lt3LQ/

```
$("#setup-ofi").click(function() {
    if ($("#closeable-ofi").css('height') === "100px") {
        $("#closeable-ofi").animate({'height': '500px', 'overflow': 'visible'}, function(){
            $("#setup-ofi").text("Hide Details \u25b2"); 
        });
    } else {
        $("#closeable-ofi").animate({'height': '100px'}, function(){
            $("#setup-ofi").text("Show Details \u25bc"); 
        });
    }
});
```

change your css:

```
#closeable-ofi {
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: this fails if you click on the link while it's animating

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery UI's effects module to animate transitions of the element's `height` property between 200 and 500.

```
$('#myDiv').animate({height: 500});
```

Set the style `overflow: hidden` on the div so that the "excess" content doesn't spill out or cause a scrollbar to appear when in the 200 pixel state.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/cnHJw/, which works even if you don't know how big the underlying div is supposed to be:

```
var hidden = false;
$('#show').click(function() {
    if (hidden) {
        $('#main').stop().animate({height: 20});
        $('#show').text('hide...');
    } else {
        var h = $('#main').get(0).scrollHeight;
        $('#main').stop().animate({height: h});
        $('#show').text('show...');
    }
    hidden = !hidden;
});
```

Comment: I dont get you. I want 200px of the content to show on page load, and onclick the remainder to slide into view, and on close, return to 200px of height of the original content being displayed. I understand overflow:hidden, but dont get what you mean in this instance.

Comment: If I create a fiddle , could you show me the way to go ? http://jsfiddle.net/3x2uG/